# Callback failing even though the statuscode is 200

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I have an odata, breeze, angular application.

Please see here: http://bepozreports.azurewebsites.net/#/dashboard

You will notice an alert that I have setup which just says the callback has failed.

If you navigate to app/js/controllers.js you will see this code

```
accountFactory.getAll()
            .then(successCallback)
            .catch(failCallback);
```

The failCallback always is called even though the call to http://bepozreports.azurewebsites.net/odata/Accounts?$orderby=FirstName results in a correct response??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your app and look at line 15199 of `breeze.debug.js`, you will find the following code:

```
 OData.read({
     requestUri: url,
     headers: { "DataServiceVersion": "2.0" }
 },
 function (data, response) {
     var inlineCount;
     if (data.__count) {
         // OData can return data.__count as a string
         inlineCount = parseInt(data.__count, 10);
     }
     return deferred.resolve({ results: data.results, inlineCount: inlineCount });
 },
 function (error) {
    return deferred.reject(createError(error, url));
 });
```

The error callback is triggered here with your url, and the error response is `message: "no handler for data"`

A failure at good error reporting by breeze.

---

After doing a little bit of digging (I'm not familiar with datajs), it looks like the problem might have something to do with your CORS setup (or lack thereof). Hope that helps.

Comment: The api is on the same domain as the app, I shouldn't need CORS right?

Comment: If it is the exact same domain (not even a different sub domain), then no. I just saw a lot of reference to CORS when looking up the no handler for data issue with datajs.

Comment: I removed the header 'DataServiceVersion' because if it is included I receive a 404!

Comment: Took a look at your metadata, you seems to have OData V4 but the DataServiceVersion mentioned above is 2.0. Don't whether this will cause the problem.